# How to tell if a GET request in Python is using an https or http proxy?

Tags: proxy, python-requests, tor

I am currently using a proxy when making get requests, via the `requests` library in Python3. I have Tor and Privoxy set up for my proxies, and the code looks like:

```
import requests
proxies = {
    "http": "http://127.0.0.1:8118",
    "https": "https://127.0.0.1:8118"
}
resp = requests.get("https://icanhazip.com", proxies=proxies)
```

I am wondering if there is a way to look in `resp` if the http or https proxy was used. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the most pythonic way is this:

```py
import requests
from urllib.parse import urlparse

def get_scheme(url):
    return urlparse(url).scheme

url = 'https://www.whatever.com'
response = requests.get(url)

scheme = get_scheme(response.url)
```

Alternatively, you could do:

```py
import requests

url = 'https://www.whatever.com'

response = requests.get(url)

scheme = response.url.split(':')[0]
```